# Does SpecFlow testing platform support async Tasks?

Tags: windows-phone-8, specflow

Async/Await support for Specflow Steps =>
I would like to use SpecFlow with the Async Await Features of C#, windows phone 8,
SpecFlow with MSTest can execute Code using async / await but doesn't wait for the Results.

I've changed BindingInvoker.cs and upgraded to .NET 4, in order to support async tasks, and receiving now IOC is not initialized errors.

https://github.com/robfe/SpecFlow/commit/507368327341e71b2f5e2a4a1b7757e0f4fb809d

Comment: How are you writing the tests?

Comment: Deleted an answer that didn't answer your question, the general gist of it is that you need the unit testing framework to support `async` not SpecFlow

Answer (score 1):

Yes. SpecFlow does support async steps
See  https://docs.specflow.org/projects/specflow/en/latest/Bindings/Asynchronous-Bindings.html
For example:

```
[When(@"I want to get the web page '(.*)'")]
public async Task WhenIWantToGetTheWebPage(string url)
{
    await _webDriver.HttpClientGet(url);
}
```

It will not continue to the next step until this step was finished but it will release the thread to perform other tests

Comment: Link changed to https://docs.specflow.org/projects/specflow/en/latest/Bindings/Asynchronous-Bindings.html

Answer (score 0):

The problem here is if i put something on background thread then in test execution mode, main thread does not know about it and it just jump to the next piece of code to exectue and verify the result, but uptill that point values are not updated on the background thread. So gives wrong assert. The way to handle this problem is make the main thread to wait/sleep untill background work is over.
Example:

```
Dim caller As AsyncMethodHandler
Dim result As IAsyncResult 
caller = New AsyncMethodHandler(AddressOf lcl_service.CreateSession)
    result = caller.BeginInvoke(parameter, Nothing, AddressOf AsyncCallback, Nothing)
        While Not result.IsCompleted
            Thread.Sleep(1)
        End While
```

Answer (score 0):

The async support is already added to SpecFlow and will be included in the text release. You can use the CI build to check it out.

See https://github.com/techtalk/SpecFlow/issues/542

Answer (score 0):

I recommend Hooks like AfterTestRun, which can be async.

```
[AfterTestRun]

public static async Task LogTestRunEnds()
```

Comment: is this an answer to the question? or a new question?